# For subsets $M\subset N$ of a vector space, $\langle{M\rangle}\subset \langle{N\rangle}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Hello I had to prove that $M\subset N$ implies $\langle{M}\rangle \subset \langle{M}\rangle$ for $M, N$ subsets of a vector space.
My idea looks like the following:
Suppose $ M = \{v_1, ..., v_m\} $ and $ N = \{v_1, ..., v_n\} $  $with \space 1 \leq m \leq n \space m,n \in N$
From that it follows by applying the definition of a linear hull:
$$〈M〉=K \cdot v_1 + ... + K \cdot v_m$$ and $$〈N〉=K \cdot v_1 + ... + K \cdot v_n$$
Because m<=n it follows that 〈M〉⊂〈N〉

Apparently that was the wrong way to do it though as i assumed that the sets are finite. Can somebody help me out here? How do you proof this correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is $K$ defined?

Comment: K is just a scalar. If my vectorspace was $R^3$ then K would be $R$.

Comment: $M \subseteq N \subseteq \langle N \rangle$, so $\langle N \rangle$ is a subspace containing $M$. Since $\langle M \rangle$ is the **smallest** subspace containing $M$ (i.e. it is the intersection of all subspaces containing $M$), we conclude that $\langle M \rangle \subseteq \langle N \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector space $V$ and a subset $X\subset V$, the space $\langle{X}\rangle$ is by definition or construction the minimal subspace of $V$ containing $X$. But $\langle{N\rangle}$ then also contains $M\subset N$, and so it must also contain $\langle{M\rangle}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since M $\subset$ N, every vector of M is also a vector of N. So a linear combination of elements of M can be viewed as a linear combination of elements in N. Thus $<M> \subset<N>.$